# loop for multiple which statements

Tags: r, loops, conditional-statements

I have a df in long format with travel data. 
The df looks like this:

```
id  from  to  traveltime  Key  departuretime  arrivaltime (next stop)
 1    2   3    00:01:00   301     08:15:00      08:16:00
 1    2   3    00:01:00   301     08:30:00      08:31:00
 1    2   3    00:01:00   301     08:45:00      08:46:00
 2    3   4    00:02:00   301     
 2    3   4    00:02:00   301     
 2    3   4    00:02:00   301
 1    5   6    00:01:00   302     09:00:00      09:01:00
 1    6   7    00:01:00   302     09:01:00      09:02:00
 2    7   8    00:01:00   302
```

Now I want to fill the empty cells. The departure time is always the sum of the arrival time and the travel time of the previous stop. So the expected output is:

```
id  from  to  traveltime  Key  departuretime  arrivaltime (next stop)
 1    2   3    00:01:00   301     08:15:00      08:16:00
 1    2   3    00:01:00   301     08:30:00      08:31:00
 1    2   3    00:01:00   301     08:45:00      08:46:00
 2    3   4    00:02:00   301     08:16:00      08:18:00
 2    3   4    00:02:00   301     08:31:00      08:33:00
 2    3   4    00:02:00   301     08:33:00      08:35:00
 1    5   6    00:01:00   302     09:00:00      09:01:00
 1    6   7    00:01:00   302     09:01:00      09:02:00
 2    7   8    00:01:00   302     09:02:00      09:03:00
```

I wrote some code that works fine. But I have to adapt the code for every edge in my df.

```
data$arrivaltime <- data$departuretime + data$traveltime
data$departuretime[which(data$id =="2" & data$Key =="301")]<-data$arrivaltime[which(data$id == "1" & data$Key =="301")]
```

This would work yet it is terrible time consuming. Cause I would need to adapt this code for every edge.
What I want to do now is to ?automate my code. So that I don't have to change the `id` and the `key` parameters manually.

I guess that I need to store the `Keys` and the `ids` in a list and then build a loop that iterates trough the `df`.

I'm new in R and I don't know how to build such a loop. So I hope that someone has an idea on that. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try looking into `dplyr::lag`. This will be easier to address if you provide a `dput` of your sample data (not clear what class your time columns are right now)

Comment: time columns are converted into hh:mm:ss fomat with der chron-package. I tried to loop through my provided code. yet it does not work out. I looked fpr ``dplyr::lag`` but could not figure out how to lag columns by multiple different values